# Securing WebAPI with Katana authentication Middleware

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I have WebAPI that is deployed in a WorkerRole on Azure with Owin.

I now want to experiment with authentication. (Remember there are no frontend as I am in a worker role).

I cant seem to find any examples or blog posts on this topic and would like to know if someone here have done anything and can point me to some examples.

I have been looking at the Microsoft.Owin.Security.* but i dont see the link for how I can use them in my owin startup.

I have put this in the startup:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ExternalAuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ExternalAuthenticationType,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ExternalAuthenticationType,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        });
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication( "hidden", "hidden");
```

What are my nexts step, how do I do the authentication when i done have a frontend. Example shown in javascript or console app will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPA template shipped with Visual Studio 2013 RC will be a good start point, which can be easily convert to a OWIN self host app by removing all MVC and ASP.NET related code.

Please check out my blog [Understanding Security Features in the SPA Template for VS2013 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx) for better understanding on the security features in SPA template.

You'd better to use bearer token instead of cookie to protect your web api. Cookie will be vulnerable with [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack.

Comment: Took at short look (busy days this week) and it indeed looked like what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It worked out great, I now started working the the RTM version. But ran my head against the wall trying ot update the ApplicationOauthProvider.  Any change you can provide a updated version? (took the nightly build and upgraded the SPA)